# Angular2 ngModel inside ngFor (Data not binding on input)

Tags: angular

This is my Angular2 application with input fields inside table. My data is displaying on `select` tag but the data binded using `ngModel` on `input` tag is not been displayed in `input` field.

```
<form name="userForm">
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let item of itemList; let in =index">
  <td><select><option >{{item.FirstName}}</option></select></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" [(ngModel)]="itemList[in].lastname"></td>
  <td><input type="text" id="middlename" name="middlename" [(ngModel)]="itemList[in].middlename"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you please remove id from your input tag, it will result in multiple elements in DOM with same id since you are running it inside a for loop. And why not use `item.lastname` and `item.middlename` instead of `item[in].lastname`

Comment: I am sure you must have imported `FormsModule` in your respective component.

Answer (score 86):

When creating multiple ngModel controls inside ngFor loop make sure to give each control unique `name`:

```
<form name="userForm">
<table>
<tr *ngFor="let item of itemList; let in = index">
  <td><input type="text" name="lastname-{{in}}" [(ngModel)]="item.lastname"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="middlename-{{in}}" [(ngModel)]="item.middlename"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: How could I access its value from my .TS file? Thanks

Comment: For those looking for solution for radio-inputs: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43582771/23715

Answer (score 0):

An alternative for Yaroslav's method: set `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` to input

P.S. make sure you know what standalone option is https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel#options