# Creating multiple radio buttons with *ngFor [Angular2]

Tags: angular

I need dynamic number of radio buttons based on the length of Array Of Objects (*eg: enum_details*):

Following is the code I tried:

```
<div *ngFor="let enum of enum_details">
  <label for="enum_answer_{{enum.value}}">
    <input id="enum_answer_{{enum.value}}" type="radio" name="enums" [(ngModel)]="enum.value">
    {{enum.display_text}}
  </label>
</div>
```

But, when I click any radio, always the last one gets selected and the value is never assigned to **ngModel**.

If I remove **ngModel**, the radios work fine, but, value is not set. What can be the fix here?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

use your code like this

```
<div *ngFor="let enum of enum_details">
      <label for="enum_answer_{{enum.name}}">
        <input id="enum_answer_{{enum.name}}" [value]='enum.name' type="radio" name="enums" [(ngModel)]="radioSelected">
        {{enum.name}}
      </label>
    </div>
    <button (click)='radioFun()'>Checked value of radio button</button>
```

## working example

<kbd>[Working example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbgdn7)</kbd>

Comment: Um, did your "working example" appear here in the past, but no more?

Comment: @WillDeStijl Hey thanks for pointing out, Example was outdated. Check now

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this.

```
   <div class="radio" *ngFor="let key of enum_details">
          <label>
                 <input type="radio" name="keys_on_hand" [value]="key.value" [(ngModel)]="key.value">
                   {{key.display}}
          </label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on @Pardeep's response, you should also make the buttons keyboard accessible for users that want/need it. Add tabindex and a keyup listener on your labels:

```
<div *ngFor="let enum of enum_details">
  <label for="enum_answer_{{enum.name}}" tabindex="0" (keyup.space)="radioSelected=enum.name'>
    <input id="enum_answer_{{enum.name}}" [value]='enum.name' type="radio" name="enums" [(ngModel)]="radioSelected">
    {{enum.name}}
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use with form control like this.

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline pl-0" *ngFor="let class of classList>
                    <input class="form-check-input" id="enum_answer_{{class.type}}" [value]='class.type' name="type" type="radio" formControlName="type">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="enum_answer_{{class.type}}">{{class.type}}</label>
                </div>
```