# Angular 2 Material - Why is my input deselected?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a weird problem.

I am using **Angular CLI** and I have added **Material 2** to it. I created some inputs with `ngfor` and bound them to `ngmodel`. Everything is working fine.

But whenever I type something, the input becomes deselected.

This is the HTML code of the component:

```
<md-input-container class="treatments" *ngFor="let t of treatment; let i = index">
    <input mdInput placeholder="treatment {{ i + 1 }}" 
      value="{{ t[i] }}" name="treatment_{{ i + 1 }}" [(ngModel)]="treatment[i]">
</md-input-container>
```

When I remove the `ngmodel`, it does work 100%.

Comment: Can you show how treatment looks like?

Comment: @Nehal It looks like
[ "treatment 1", "treatment 2", "etc..." ]
Thats it ... ( not a relevent question - how i can change my name from the mobile version of stack overflow - ).
Thanks

Comment: @TheSnake620 How did it ever go with either of the answers provided? :)

Comment: @AJT_82 i have tested the second one with trackBy, amd deleted the value attr, and does work very will( if i did not delete the value attr it just write 2 letters and then any letter i wrrite it deletes the letter before it ), i will test the first answer later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are iterating over an Array of primitive type, and thus they are compared by value. When you change a treatment (i.e `t`), all values are destroyed and new ones created, which causes the field to loose focus. This can be solved by using `trackBy`, which tracks the treatments by the index and only destroys and recreates the treatment you are modifying.

So add `trackBy`:

```
<md-input-container class="treatments" *ngFor="let t of treatment; 
    let i = index; trackBy:trackByFn">
```

and in TS add the function:

```
trackByFn(index, treatment) {
  return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to bind `ngModel` to primitive values. You can solve the deselect problem by adding `@Input()` before the `treatment` declaration.

```
@Input() treatment: string[] = [ "treatment 1", "treatment 2"];
```

But it will not update the values in the array. If you want the values to update, `ngModel` needs to bind with object property. I have added both examples in this [Plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/X0WeMn?p=preview).

For more info, refer this SO question
[Angular2 ngModel inside of ngFor](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38423663/5556177)

Comment: I really can't see why you mentioned `@Input` since the question isn't about passing data via components... Anyway, it's worth to mention that the `value="{{ t[i] }}"` is also a problem, it was conflicting with `ngModel` there.

Comment: @Nehal Your Way didn't work, i have to use trackBy, BTW Thanks for your help :).